# How to run Jurassic (js engine) on wp7 and wp8

Tags: javascript, windows, windows-phone-7, jurassic

I've tried to install jurassic on my project using nuget, well, on windows 8 no problems it works, but neither in windows phone 7 and windows phone 8 won't compile...

any Ideas, I know (from comment on site) that on wp7 and wp8 can works but I really not understand how ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the answer is:

for Unknow reason nuget package put wrong dll into reference so the solution is to recompile the project for windows phone 7, works great also for 8 and windows desktop :)